# Ethernet disconnected., Im offline

Tags: network-manager, offline

Till yesterday my network was working fine, but when today in the morning when i try to use the internet i am getting an error saying disconnected you are offline, i am aware that there are many similar posts about this i have tried so many tips like nothing is working please help, i am new to UBUNTU  by the way... Thanks

Things i have tried are:
Resetting my network manager
Restarting my laptop
installing r8168-dkms
Deleting my network connection( when i restarted a new connection was automatically created named auto Ethernet with same settings as previos)

Comment: OK, can you try pinging your Router? Do you know how to find the IP of your router if not? I can show you how, if not. You can probably find it easily by searching for your router's name and "default gateway IP"

Comment: I don't know if this is right but i typed this : ip route | grep default
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlp6s0  proto static  metric 600

Comment: May be a router issue. Have you tried connecting the computer to anything else (and also does the router work with anything else)?

Comment: Do you know what all those terms do?  I'm not sure about that. Like I said  all you have to do is search your router up and ping it

Comment: @Wilf   I am sorry i dont have a router its a direct wired connection, sorry for my mistakes..

Comment: Oh ok. If is a connection directly from a ISP to a house, or are in a some apartment?

Comment: It is saying network is unreachable ..

Comment: ISP to a house...

Comment: You probably need to phone the ISP and ask then. Though normally you will have a router (THIS CAN BE WIRED, not always just wireless :)) which takes the connection from outside the house and maps it into a home network. Did you enter authentication when you first set up the connection (and it worked)?

Comment: Basically when i switch on my laptop there is a authentication page that pops up every time but today i did not pop, i even tried going over that page but it says network is disconnected.., I never had these problems in windows maybe i did something which i shouldn't have done..

Comment: what did you do? botching the firmware may of broken it, or reconfiguring your outside connection (in the latter instance you can usually get help from your ISP). In case of err ..illegitimate.. activity you may of had your connection blocked, in which case you need to contact your ISP anyway.

Comment: I did nothing as such, just watched a movie online yesterday and today im not able to connect..; the whole day i was trying to fix but nothing helps..

Comment: I think it is an ISP problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 so should i call up the provider and ask for their assistance?

Comment: That is correct. Most likely that will help.